# How to convert PX value to flutter font size

Tags: flutter, fonts, flutter-layout, font-size, flutter-test

For example, if I set 40px for the title (in adobe XD design) how to convert it to the exact flutter font size

because I can't understand the flutter font-size property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

40px in Adobe XD means 40px in Flutter. You can read the [official document](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextStyle/fontSize.html). Flutter font-size:

> The size of glyphs (in logical pixels) to use when painting the text.

You can be confused about [devicePixelRatio](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Window/devicePixelRatio.html). You can find pt to px conversion from [here](http://pttopx.com/).

Comment: How to convert points to pixels in flutter ? My UI/UX designer gave 10pt. So it is 13.33333 pixels. It is not good way to convert in online for each and every font. Is there any official flutter package to convert via programatically in flutter app itself ?

Answer (score -1):

Well, if you do use Figma, Adobe XD for your design, I will suggest that you use this flutter package called [flutter_screenutl](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screenutil) , check out the documentation.

- Set your ScreenUtlInit's design size property to your Figma design size (Width and height).
  Then if your figma text specifies 20px, use 20.sp on flutter.

---

Comment: hi, Opeyemi. how are things doing using this package? thanks

Comment: I've been using it in all my major projects.
Especially if so much info needs to be fused to the screen, and you want it to be the same on different devices.